# NAT on Cisco ASA 5505 not working due to 'implicit' ACL

Tags: networking, routing, nat, vlan

I am trying to route between VLANs on a Cisco ASA 5505. [I read here that deleting all the ACLs and re-adding them may help](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/firewalling/inter-vlan-routing-on-an-asa-5505-9-1/td-p/2443513), so I did so but it did not. I then ran a packet trace and it returned:
`Config Implicit Rule. (aci-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule.`

Researching this further, I found [this link that states NAT rules are to blame](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/firewalling/asa-5520-flow-is-denied-by-configured-rule/m-p/2214610#M109351) for the issue. Naturally, I deleted my NAT rules...and this broke my routing. For whatever reason I am not able to get the dynamic NAT rule working again. What could I be doing wrong here?

Additionally, if anyone can help me with routing between VLANs I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit denial means that unless a packet matches an explicit rule in an ACL, it will be dropped.  To change this behaviour, append the following to the last line of the ACL:

`permit ip any any`

This explicitly allows any packet through that hadn't matched an earlier `deny` statement.  If `ip any any` is too broad, craft a suitable `permit` that corresponds to your specific network.